# ThreadPool using Future for HTTP Request Java

Tags: java, multithreading, http, post, request

I'm trying to send http post request using soap+xml as the body to a server and make my thread pool fixed to 1000. I tried to request 100 times and got some of the response back below 20 seconds but some more than 20 seconds which is my connection timeout. All 100 requests ran at the same time.

I tried lowering down the pool to 10 threads and it finishes all the process in under 5 seconds with every request returning the response in under 5 seconds even though only 10 requests can run in one time.

If I only request 10 http post for each thread pool size, both returned the response in 3 seconds.

I'm trying to make a web service which probably hundreds or thousands of users will access at the same time with maybe 10 or more requests per user. I make the thread pool as static, so only 1 thread pool instance is created.
If I lower down the thread pool, I'm afraid many requests have to wait and it will create a bottleneck. Make the thread pool high for instance 1000 will make the response slow per request. I also tried http request to other sites and the same thing happen even though it was a little bit faster sending back the response than the server I'm trying to use.

I don't know if this was caused by too many connections from one computer and is only affecting my computer requests and not other users requests. Or will this affect other user request as well.

My question are: 
- is this the cause of too many connections to the server at one time making it slow, or does too many threads running at the same time affects each other? 
- should I lower the thread pool or just make it high? (if no alternate solution)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you are reaching a point where more threads just means more synchronization effort rather than more bandwidth.

In general, when in doubt, plot a chart with the X axis as the number of threads and the Y axis as the performance (of course, try to use best practices for benchmarking, such as averaging several samples to generate each point, and using warmup periods before each sample). Then you can see where you hit optimal performance.

Nothing beats the scientific method!

Comment: Hmm I see your point, I guess most of those threads will probably be hanging around waiting for responses from DB or something. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback guys. Can a thread pool be portioned for a user? lets say I have a thread pool fixed at 1000 and I want to allocate 10 threads maximum per user from those thread pool. If the request are larger than the available threads lets say the user enters 5 requests but the available threads are only 3 than it would wait until minimum 5 threads are available? 

If I'm making sense that is.

Comment: I don't really feel qualified to answer this with any confidence. Perhaps if you have a queue of incoming request, you could check an AtomicInteger currentlyRunningRequests for the user before processing the request, and if it's too high, return the request to the tail of the queue instead of processing it? A kind of abstract turnstyle.

Just watch out you don't use up tons of memory just for the user lookup map or something like that. And maybe ask this in a separate question, to attract attention from other people.